# What is more acceptable—"Hopkins's" or "Hopkins'"?

Tags: possessives

The title is fairly self-explanatory, but I was wondering how one would write/say the possessive form of the name "Hopkins". Is it " Hopkins's " or " Hopkins' " or are both acceptable?

Comment: This is not an absolute rule, but most people seem to accept "Use  Hopkins's if you want three syllables to be pronounced, but Hopkins' if you want two". In spite of Google data showing the favoured form in print here being the former.

Comment: There seems to be no consensus in this particular case, if these [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hopkins%27+poems%2CHopkins%27s+poems&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHopkins%20%27%20poems%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHopkins%20%27s%20poems%3B%2Cc0) are anything to go by. (Can't link; enter Hopkins' poems,Hopkins's poems in an Ngram search).

Comment: Strange. I believe you're both incorrect. The correct grammar is Hopkins', and it's pronounced with three syllables. Check out this link. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/apostrophe#apostrophes_showing_possession